# MVC PHP + AJAX não consigo passar return json_encode para o response do ajax

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

**Ola a todos e agradeço desde já**

Tenha a classe de validação do form onde pega todos os erros do form:

```
// Validação final do cadastro
    public function validateFinalCadastro($arrVar) {

            if(count($this->getErro())>0){
                    $arrResponse=[
                        "retorno"=>"erro",
                        "erros"=>$this->getErro()
                    ];


                }else{
                    $arrResponse=[
                        "retorno"=>"success",
                        "erros"=>null
                    ];

            }

            return json_encode($arrResponse, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    }
```

Aqui tenho o Controller que passa para view:

```
 public function teste() {
            //echo 'esse é um teste';
            $this->recVariaveis();

            $validate = new ClassValidate();
            $validate->validateFields($_POST);
            $validate->validateEmail($this->Email);
            $validate->validateIssetEmail($this->Email);
            $validate->validateData($this->DataNascimento);
            $validate->validateCpf($this->Cpf);
            $validate->validateConfSenha($this->Senha,$this->SenhaConf);
            $validate->validateStrongSenha($this->Senha);                
            $validate->validateCaptcha($this->gRecaptchaResponse);
            $validate->validateFinalCadastro($this->arrVar);
    }
```

Se eu dar um echo, print ou vardump na $validate->validateFinalCadastro($this->arrVar); consigo passar ela pra view e apresentar o erro ...ele apresenta depois do fechamento do html da pagina...

{"retorno":"erro","erros":["Email já cadastrado!","Utilize uma senha mais forte!","Sistema de segurança foi ativado! Atualize a página e tente novamente ou aguarde mais um pouco."]}

Aqui esta o ajax sem datatype: 'json'

Sem datatype: 'json' eu entro no success reponse mais caio no else, porque o response.retorno esta sem o datatype: 'json'.

$('#FormCadastroClientes').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var dados=$(this).serialize();
    console.log(dados);

```
$.ajax({
    url: getRoot()+'CadastroClientes/teste',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    data: dados,
    success: function (response) {
        $('.retornoCad').empty();
        if(response.retorno == 'erro'){
            getCaptcha();
            $.each(response.erros,function(key,value){
                $('.retornoCad').append(value+'');
            });
        }else{
            $('.retornoCad').append('Dados inseridos com sucesso!');
        }
    },

    error: function (response, jqXHR, request, status, errorThrown, erro) {

            console.log(response);
            //alert(dados);                                     
            console.log(dados);                                     
            //alert(jqXHR);                                     
            console.log(jqXHR);                                     
            //alert(request);                                     
            console.log(request);                                     
            //alert(status);  
            console.log(status);  
            //alert(errorThrown); 
            console.log(errorThrown); 
            //alert(erro);                                      
            console.log(erro);                                      

         },

    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            //colocar aqui algo que deseja que faça ao terminar todo o processo (finnaly)

    }

});
```

Ajax com datatype: 'json' nao consigo entrar no success ele já cai no erro

```
$('#FormCadastroClientes').on('submit', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var dados=$(this).serialize();
console.log(dados);

$.ajax({
    url: getRoot()+'CadastroClientes/teste',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dados,
    success: function (response) {
        $('.retornoCad').empty();
        if(response.retorno == 'erro'){
            getCaptcha();
            $.each(response.erros,function(key,value){
                $('.retornoCad').append(value+'');
            });
        }else{
            $('.retornoCad').append('Dados inseridos com sucesso!');
        }
    },

    error: function (response, jqXHR, request, status, errorThrown, erro) {

            console.log(response);
            //alert(dados);                                     
            console.log(dados);                                     
            //alert(jqXHR);                                     
            console.log(jqXHR);                                     
            //alert(request);                                     
            console.log(request);                                     
            //alert(status);  
            console.log(status);  
            //alert(errorThrown); 
            console.log(errorThrown); 
            //alert(erro);                                      
            console.log(erro);                                      

         },

    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            //colocar aqui algo que deseja que faça ao terminar todo o processo (finnaly)

    }

});
```

Observações:
- Consigo inserir no banco tudo ok.
- Consigo apresentar o rertun json_encode direto na view
- Consigo entrar no success do ajax sem usar datatype: 'json' não entro no if para ler o array mais entro no else.

Eu recebo esse erros no console.log

No response eu teria que receber o return do json_encode e não recebo. O que eu recebo é o html da view.

O ajax esta esperando um retorno em json e nao o html da pagina.

parsererror 
SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Obrigado a todos.....atecipadamente

Comment: Só pra ter certeza, o `dataType` definido no AJAX é referente ao formato do corpo da **requisição** não da resposta

Comment: Qual o retorno do Ajax?

Comment: Ola Guilherme, quando dou submit no form eu pego os dados com serialize e adiciono na var = dados ok... url: getRoot()+'CadastroClientes/teste', é onde eu envio para o controller, type: 'post', é o metodo que envio pra controller, dataType: 'json', é o retorno do controller caso não passar por alguma validação, data: dados são os dados que envio para o controller inserir no banco...  ..´so que json não recebe os erros do controller

Comment: Sam a responsta esta aqui...

Comment: readyState: 4
​---------------   o b.o esta aqui em vez de receber o return do json recebo o html da pagina da view-------------------
responseText: "<!doctype html>\n\n\n\n<html lang=\"pt-br\">…"​                                        -----------------------------
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()​
state: function state()​
status: 200​
statusCode: function statusCode()​
statusText: "OK"
then: function then()​
<prototype>: Object { … }

Comment: parsererror 
SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: O problema é esse. O Ajax deve chamar uma página que retorne **apenas** o JSON, **e não** uma página comum, com HTML e tudo mais.

Comment: Sam o que recomenda... criar uma view sem nada, hum...eu uso o layout com as tags metas/header/html ...não sei...

Comment: Hum.. deu fatalcrash na minha memoria....rsrrs

Comment: Vc vai criar um arquivo só com o código que retorna o JSON e chamar esse arquivo no Ajax.

Comment: Vou fazer aqui e já retorno

Comment: Sam.... Consegui como você disse. dentro da minha controller tinha um construct que renderiza-a toda layout e por isso ele trazia o o html da pagina primeiro, exclui o construct do layout e funcionou... obrigado pela ajuda vou melhorar minha lojica abraçosssss....

Comment: Isso mesmo. É porque o Ajax retorna tudo que estiver na página. É como se vc estivesse abrindo a página direto. O que tiver no código-fonte é o que o Ajax retorna.

Comment: Obrigado ........ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema consiste em que o Ajax está retornando toda uma página HTML completa (uma *view*), quando o esperado é apenas o JSON puro. Isso resulta em erro pois virão tags HTML que não pertencem ao JSON resultando em erro no parser:

> parsererror SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1
>   column 1 of the JSON data"

O correto é que o Ajax faça a requisição a um arquivo que contenha apenas o código onde é retornado o JSON, ou seja, as validações e o controller, dando um `echo` no JSON criado.